# Which is the correct/optimal way of declaring MAVEN dependencies in order to create scalable projects?

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3, pom.xml

So I'm working in a project with the following way of declaring dependencies, then I came to the question if this is a scalable/appropriate way or is there any better formula.

The first thing we do is declare the dependency in the current project, **without specifying the version section**:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dependency</groupId>
      <artifactId>dependency1</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then we **delegate the version allocation to a secondary pom**, lets call it "common-management.pom", every project delegates to this one (that means: every project imports this pom to manage their dependencies versions)

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.company</groupId>
         <artifactId>common-management</artifactId>
         <type>pom</type>
         <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
```

Now we change to the common-management.pom and **declare a variable** with the version for this dependency

```
<properties>
   <variable1.version>1.0.0</variable.version>
</properties>
```

Finally we **associate the dependency with its version** in the dependencyManagment section of the common-management.pom

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.dependency</groupId>
         <artifactId>dependency1</artifactId>
         <version>${variable1.version}</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
```

Any comment would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds perfectly legal. What's the question? When you run it, is there an error occurring?

Comment: Usually I prefer to use a parent pom where I can set all the common parameters that will be shared by the other projects: dependency versions, repository location, etc...

Comment: My question is if there is a better of more efficient way of managing dependencies in Maven that leads to more scalable projects.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reasonable approach.

You replace a lot of version numbers with just one. This makes it easier to keep versions consistent. Two further aspects:

- It only makes sense to align all these versions if the projects are somehow interconnected. If you have completely separated areas, it may be better to have one BOM ("secondary pom") per area because otherwise you implicitly tie the two areas together.
- The approach does not guarantee that everyone uses the same versions because one still has to update the version of the BOM. In many cases this is an advantage, though, because not everybody has to update at the same time. If, on the other hand, you always build all your projects at the same time, a multi-module project may be the better choice.